# Webkit equivalent of :-moz-system-metric(touch-enabled)

Tags: webkit, css, touch, media-queries

[:-moz-system-metric(touch-enabled)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:-moz-system-metric(touch-enabled)) looks like a really useful CSS selector for working on mobile sites.

Unfortunately Webkit is dominant on mobile touch devices so does anyone know if there is a Webkit equivalent?

(Ideally it'd be good if this was managed by CSS3 media queries)

**Edit:** [Looks like it is supported in Gecko as a media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Media_queries#-moz-touch-enabled)

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to accomplish this without resorting to Javascript, at present.

As @easwee said, [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is a well-regarded JS library that focuses on feature detection. You can use its `touch` test for your use case.

If you don't need all of Modernizr's bells and whistles, you can do the following:

A) Load the following JS as early in your `<body>` tag as you can:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if( !!window.TouchEvent ) body.className += " touch-enabled ";
</script>
```

B) Write your CSS. Since Gecko uses a media query to inform you of touch availability, you'll have to dupe the touch-specific CSS, like so:

```
BODY.touch-enabled DIV.foo
{
    /* touch-specific CSS */
}

@media screen and (-moz-touch-enabled)
{
DIV.foo
{
    /* touch-specific CSS */
}

}
```

If the per-selector code is identical in both circumstances, GZIP ought to optimize away some of the duplication. (You are using compression, I hope.)

Answer (score 2):

In Ian Wessman's answer the test `!!window.TouchEvent` works incorrectly. In current desktop Chrome (23.0.1271.52, Linux) `window.TouchEvent` is a function, so Ian's code considers the browser touch-enabled.

If you want short code, it's probably best to copy-paste the [relevant code from Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/touchevents.js).

Comment: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/touchevents.js

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is another browser that tried to implement a similar selector but unfortunately it was removed out for now.

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) could be and interesting detection tool since it can detect touch events too.

http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#touch