# How to write CSS media queries to detect a touchscreen device?

Tags: css, touch

I believe I should design my site for different input approaches. I believe the mainstream input types are mouse+keyboard and touchscreen. I want to use CSS to detect if my user uses a touch input. I want to increase lineheight of a linklist so that it's easier to select with a finger.

Is this possible?

Comment: maybe that can help you : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373169/webkit-equivalent-of-moz-system-metrictouch-enabled][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373169/webkit-equivalent-of-moz-system-metrictouch-enabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media query to detect if device is touchscreen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387805/media-query-to-detect-if-device-is-touchscreen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to use CSS to detect if my user uses a touch input.

In 2019, pretty much all browsers can now understand `interaction @media queries`:

```
@media only screen and (hover: none) {

  [... CSS HERE...]
}
```

indicates that the **primary** interaction method *is not* a **mouse-pointer** (or similar device with hover capability).

This usually means that the primary interaction method *is* **touch**.

---

**Browser compatibility**

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-interaction

Answer (score 1):

According to this article there are no "reliable" ways of detecting touch devices yet:
http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/

The way I usually go with this is to use CSS media queries to detect the different screen sizes. You could have a stylesheet with a media query for each device resolution, which is the total size available on the *device* and not only the *screen* (the browser size).
See this cheat-sheet for inspiration:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Hope it helps.

Edit: the screen sizes will tell you which device is likely viewing the current page

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't sound like a sane or eligant design approach. Sounds like a hack to me.

Comment: Alright I understand. You should try the Modernizr library at least then - I think you will get a more stable solution according to your needs.

See: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/detect-touch-device-modernizr/